# Ruby on Rails, validate uniqueness of an attribute concatenated with a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, client-side

I have an attribute, `:group_name`, that has to be validated for uniqueness on the client side.
BUT first, I need to attach a string to the attribute and only then validate it. Please, do not ask me why, I need it=)

I have a form:

```
 <%= form_for Group.new, url: what_to_do_groups_path ,method: :get ,:validate => true do |f| %>
 <div class="field_label">
<%= f.label :group_name%>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%=f.text_field :group_name %>
</div>
<%= submit_tag "Submit",  :commit =>"submit" %>

<br class="clear" />
<br />
<%end%>
```

controller:

```
attr_accessible  :group_name
validates :group_name,      :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}
```

So, the user types in "RedBull". The `:group_name` has a value of "RedBull". I want to attach a string "_Marc" and only validate (client side) in the database, if there is another group called "RedBull_Marc"
How can I do it?

May I do something like this?

```
validates :group_name+"_Marc",      :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}
```

And if I have multiple strings to attach in order to check if such groups are already in the database.
Like I want to check if "RedBull_Marc" or "RedBull_Kate" are in the database
So I can do it with regex, like this : /_(Marc|Katja)/ but where should I build it?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
Client side validation should be present.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`before_validation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) hook to modify the attribute before it gets validated.  You could also write your own custom validation that did the concatenation, but it's probably best to use `before_validation` as that's what it is meant for.

The model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_name

  validates :group_name, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}

  before_validation :add_to_group_name

  protected
  def add_to_group_name
    self.group_name = group_name + '_Marc' # Edit however you want to here
  end
end
```

If you need to check the database for multiple values, you won't be able to with just a uniqueness validation, so you'll have to write a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods) that searches the database for you.  For your use case, it looks like you could use a `like` query:

```
# % is a wildcard character and matches anything
# So group_name + "%" will match anything starting with group_name
User.where("group_name like ?", group_name + "%")
```

So your model would have a custom validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_name

  validate :check_group_name_uniqueness

  def check_group_name_uniqueness
    if User.where("group_name like ?", group_name + "%").count > 0
      errors.add(:group_name, "is already taken")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is with multiple concatenation? I need to look if "RedBull_Kate" or "RedBull_Marc" oder "Redbull_Pip" in the database are? And I need to do it just after the user types in the name of the group. With your method I can look only for one concatenation.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to write a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods) that searches the database for all of the values you're looking for.  It may depend on what database you're using, but you might be able to search for something like `RedBull_*`.

Comment: Your custom validation is not a client side validation anymore, isn't it?

Comment: You can validate it with a JavaScript request, but the validation will have to be done in Rails because the clientside can only access the database through an API.  You can submit the Rails form with JavaScript and to the user, it will seem all on the clientside.

Comment: You may want to look into Rails [client side validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations).